# I can't pass the information in the firestore to the properties of the object in kotlin

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

There is data in the following structure in Firestore:

> link1 i.stack.imgur.com/jUwPE.png

```
collection: Cards
Document: albus
field : resim
```

I want to save all of this data in the object I created in kotlin as follows:

```
    lateinit var decoded_cardBackground : Bitmap
    lateinit var decoded_card1: Bitmap

    init{

        var collection = Firebase.firestore.collection("Cards")

        collection.document("albus").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener{ document->

            val base64 = document.data!!["resim"].toString()
            val imageBytes = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT)
            decoded_card1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
            }
        }
```

Then I want to use this data in another activity:

```
val card = CardsFromFirebase()
CardsBackground = card.decoded_cardBackground
card1 = card.decoded_card1
card2 = card.decoded_card1
```

I tried to adapt my code using Picasso library. but I can't use it because of the structure I'm     using.

Comment: The problem is almost always that `card1 = card.decoded_card1` runs before `decoded_card1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)` due to the asynchronous nature of loading data from Firestore. You can most easily validate if that's the case by setting breakpoints on both of those lines, running in the debugger, and checking in which order they get invoked.

Comment: As Frank mentioned in his comment, Firebase API is asynchronous. Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore).